# When adding the word "Nora" when carrying out the Torah

Tags: tefilla

According to the custom of the Ashkenaz (Nusach Sphard), when carrying out the Torah, on Yamim Noraim, the word "Nora" is added and they say "Kadosh veNora Shmo". I saw that some also add it on Hol HaMoed, Sukkot and Hoshana Rabbah. I would like to know when it is customary to add the word 'Nora'? Is it also added on Shabbat Teshuvah, Sukkot, Hol HaMoed Sukkot and Hoshana Rabbah?

Comment: The question is backwards. That word is part of the original nusach for always. Only in the acharonim do we start to find [criticism of] some chazzanim starting to drop it on most days. Perhaps to be cute people started emphasizing the word נורא on ימים נוראים  (the way some still do for the word מלך) and then it had the opposite effect where people thought the traditional wording was somehow inappropriate for other days.

Comment: Some add it on Simchas Torah